# Why success callback is not called in extjs form submission?

Tags: file-upload, extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to upload a file using Ext JS forms and in case of success or failure, show appropriate messages. But I'm not able to get the desired result. I'm not able to make `success` or `failure` callbacks work in `form.submit` action.

What I've done till now is:

Creating a form with this script:

```
new Ext.FormPanel({
    fileUpload: true,
    frame: true,
    url: '/profiler/certificate/update',
    success: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    },
    failure: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
}).getForm().submit()


​/*
    The response Content-Type is text/html (with charcode=utf8);
    The response JSON is: { "success": true }
*/​​
```

Setting the response `Content-Type` to `text/html` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6227369/811785).
Sending an appropriate JSON result back, based on [Ext JS docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Submit). The response captured via Fiddler is:

```
{"success":false}
```

or

```
{"success":true}
```

I even set the response Content-Type to `application/json`. But still no success.

I've read links like [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?111794-Success-handler-not-getting-called-in-file-upload-using-extjs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053690/extjsdjango-form-submit-success-failure-issue), but none of them helped. Please note that I also tried another script which creates a form, with an upload field in it, and a save button, and I submitted the form in the handler of the save button. But still no callback is fired.

Comment: **Notes:** I have to use Ext JS in this project, and as a web developer I truly hate it. Documentation really sucks. Help over net is not that much. Learning curve is a big problem. Styling web almost becomes a nightmare, it's not developer friendly, etc.

Comment: That's another reason I hate Ext JS. Post a question about jQuery and you receive ten answers in half an hour. Post an Ext JS question, and you end up like this.

Comment: The answer is clearly there in the documentation. Nowhere does it say the success/failure are configs of the form.Panel or form.Basic. Rather, they are passed to the submit method as demonstrated: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-submit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a working example - Javascript code:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.define('ImagePanel', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        fileUpload: true,
        title: 'Upload Panel',
        width: 300,
        height: 100,

        onUpload: function () {
            this.getForm().submit({
                url: 'upload.php',
                scope: this,
                success: function (formPanel, action) {
                    var data = Ext.decode(action.response.responseText);
                    alert("Success: " + data.msg);
                },
                failure: function (formPanel, action) {
                    var data = Ext.decode(action.response.responseText);
                    alert("Failure: " + data.msg);
                }
            });
        },

        initComponent: function () {
            var config = {
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
                        buttonText: 'Upload',
                        name: 'uploadedFile',
                        listeners: {
                            'change': {
                                scope: this,
                                fn: function (field, e) {
                                    this.onUpload();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            };

            Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });


    var panel = Ext.create('ImagePanel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

And PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES)) {
    $temp_file_name = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'];
    $original_file_name = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'];

    echo '{"success": true, "msg": "'.$original_file_name.'"}';

} else {
    echo '{"success": false, "msg": "No Files"}';
}
```

Comment: Fixed quoting in JSON returned by PHP.

Comment: Just works, but I still don't understand the theory. As a developer, another time I say *damn Ext JS*.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879008/success-handler-not-getting-called-in-file-upload-using-extjs/6227369#6227369) might help explain the theory.

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with this for quite some time now as well. Here's my code:

```
Ext.getCmp('media-upload-form').getForm().doAction('submit', {
    url: './services/recordmedia/upload',
    method: 'post',
    waitMsg: 'Please wait...',
    params: {
        entityId: this.entityId,
    },
    failure: function(form, action){
        alert(_('Error uploading file'));
        this.fireEvent('file-upload');
        this.close();
    },
    success: function(form, action){
        this.fireEvent('file-upload');
        this.close();
    },
    scope: this
})
```

The response was always wrapped in <pre> tags by the browser, what caused the Extj lib not to call the callbacks. To fix this:

- make sure your server returns the correct json: {"success":true}
- make sure that the content-type is set to text/html

Answer (score -1):

Actually, this is well covered by docs for Ext.form.Panel and Ext.form.Basic. The problem with your code not working is that there are no config options "success", "failure" for the form panel. You should put them in the config object passed to the submit action. So your code should look like:

```
new Ext.FormPanel({
    fileUpload: true,
    frame: true


}).getForm().submit({
    url: '/profiler/certificate/update',
    success: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    },
    failure: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
});
```

Note the difference: In Ext 4, there is a form component (Ext.form.Panel) which is basically a view component concerned with how you form looks, and then there is the underlying form class (e.g. Ext.form.Basic) concerned with the functionality. Form submissions are handled by Ext.form.Basic (or whatever returned by your `form.getForm()`).

Comment: The formpanel inherits the submit method (helper function), which is why this answer was voted down by someone.