# ExtJS 4 Form.submit() without sucess:true in answer

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a [form](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel), which submitted like this:

```
form.submit({
                url: '/postme',
                waitMsg: 'Loading...',
                method: 'POST',
                success: function (form, action) {
                   console.log(action.response.responseText);                                   
                }
            });
```

But! The main thing that in answer I don't have property `success: true` and cannot manage to add it. Is there is a way to make something like `callback` parameter in [Ext.Ajax.request](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request) 
instead of `success`? Or maybe there is a way to tell form.submit() that it must detect success in other responce parameter?

BTW: a cannot use Ext.Ajax.request because I have to pass multipart data from form (file upload).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic) explains that you have to pass `success: true` for the success handler to be called. This is the doc for the `submit` method

> @param {Object} options
>   The options to pass to the action (see Ext.form.Basic.submit and Ext.form.Basic.doAction for details)

```
if (form.isValid()) {
    // Submit the Ajax request and handle the response
    form.submit({
        success: function(form, action) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.message);
        },

        // If you don't pass success:true, it will always go here
        failure: function(form, action) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result ? action.result.message : 'No response');
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to use a different property to indicate an error, you should look into http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-cfg-errorReader, you can configure the errorReader to read your property as you would like.

You can also route both your success and failure handlers to the same place and do determine it from the handler

Be sure to set `standardSubmit:true` so it doesn't get submitted with AJAX

**Sample solution that will make your code feel a little bit less dirty**

```
Ext.define('ns.my.CustomReader', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Reader', 
    alias: 'reader.ns-customreader',
    read: function(xhr) 
         var resp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText, true);
         // Handle the case where response is not JSON too (unhandled server errror?)
         return {success: resp ? !!resp.id : false};
    }
});
```

Then, when you create the form, you can just use

```
 form : {
     errorReader: 'ns-customreader'
 }
```

I also noticed that you're not returning the record, which a reader should do according to the documentation, it may be that you just don't need it, but it'd be nice to satisfy the interface to keep your code in line with Ext-JS

> The errorReader does not have to be a full-blown implementation of a Reader. It simply needs to implement a read(xhr) function which returns an Array of Records in an object with the following structure:

```
{ records: recordArray } // I think it needs success: boolean also.
```

Comment: And what's the point? I looked to api, and haven't find solution to tell, that response can be successful even if in answer from server there is no param `success: true`. As I said I need something like `callback` parameter in [Ext.Ajax.request](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request)

Comment: @AndrewKevich It will be routed to the failure port if you don't pass `success:true`, just handle it there? You can't add `success: boolean` to your response?

Comment: @AndrewKevich  If you really want another parameter to determine if it's an error, you'll need to pass in an `Ext.data.reader.Reader` as the `errorReader` config http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-cfg-errorReader

Comment: Thanks! Also looked into errorReader and made a bit dirty hack.

Comment: @AndrewKevich It's not that dirty, the documentation does say that all an error reader really needs is a function called `read` that takes an `XHR` and returns a list of the records, With your solution, I don't understand how you are returning the record that was created. Is that because you don't need it? See my edit for how to make it feel cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't send a `success: true` it will obviously be a failure. So handle your parameter in the failure callback function similar to this, where your alternative to `success` is `status`:

```
form.submit({
    url: '/postme',
    waitMsg: 'Loading...',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function (form, action) {
        console.log(action.response.responseText);                                   
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {
        if (action.result.status == true) {
            console.log('success!');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Juan Mendes answer I found the following conditions need to be true:

On the server side

- The correct json needs to have a **success** *true*: {"success":true}
- The returned contentType must be set to **text/html**

This is true for version extjs-3.4.0

Please look at: [Why success callback is not called in extjs form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110084/why-success-callback-is-not-called-in-extjs-form-submission)

This saved me a lot of time and I hope it helps someone else.